# What is the algorithm/formula for natural leaf decay?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

This question is more out of curiosity than anything else. The Wiki and other places do mention that leaves decay once their tree is cut down (but not if you place them of course), but there doesn't seem to be any details as to the decay formula by tick, as there seems to be from growing crops. Does anybody know what this formula is? Thanks.

I am currently playing Minecraft 1.6.2.

Comment: I always assumed it was random, so if you want to get into artificial randomization formulas, then good luck.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I believe it is, but so is growing crops. There's still an algorithm, even if it includes (pseudo)random aspects.

Comment: Yes, I'm not so much interested in the artificial pseudorandomness so much as the formula I assume is programmed around it.

Comment: If you are a developer, the code behind the leaf decay may be of use to you: https://gist.github.com/IQAndreas/5976815 I'll try to clean it up and see if I can get a proper answer from it.

Comment: Thank you - I'm not a developer or programmer of any sort so I can't really make much out of that snippet of code, but it is nice to see that it would be possible to get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Once every game tick, 3 random blocks in every 16<sup>3</sup> block section close to you are assigned "block ticks". On blocks that support them, random activities such as plant growth and leaf decay occur on these block ticks.

Do note that block ticks only occur on blocks near you (that is to say, anywhere in a 15x15 [chunk](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunks) square centered on the chunk you're in). This means being just far enough away from leaves so that the chunks they are part of are still rendered, but are not candidates for block ticks, might mean they never decay until you return.

Comment: So, the probability for plant growth (a single stage) is the same as leaf decay?

Comment: @inkyvoyd Yes. However, it is entirely possible for either of those processes to complete much faster than the other, since I am not aware of how many block ticks it takes to complete plant growth vs leaf decay.

Comment: Not all block-update-dependent things occur with 100% chance on block tick. Also, game tick occurs every 1/20th of a second.

Comment: @OrcJMR That depends on what the update method of the block does. Some custom blocks decide to skip update ticks randomly, whereas some only do something every n update ticks. Regarding "game tick occurs every 1/20th of a second", I don't think I implied otherwise.

Comment: @Asad Not to prove you wrong, I just thought it is useful to mention.